Next.js 14 App Router: Code after return still executing, causing unexpected behavior
Issue:
I'm encountering an issue in a Next.js 14 App Router project where code after a return statement is still being executed, even though the condition for returning a component is met. This behavior causes unexpected side effects such as extra API calls being made after the return.
Note: This issue occurs only when deployed on Vercel. The same code works as expected in my local environment without any issues.

Context:
I'm using Next.js 14 App Router for a page that handles user pre-registration. In this flow, after a user submits the form, the registration ID is saved in a cookie, and the user is redirected to a confirmation message page, indicating the next steps. The confirmation message page should return a success message informing the user that a confirmation email has been sent, and the function should stop executing any further code.
This behavior works as expected in my local environment, but on the server (Vercel), code after the return statement continues to execute, triggering unintended API requests.
Here is the relevant portion of the code:
export default async function Page({ searchParams }) {
  console.log(typeof window === 'undefined' ? 'Server-side render' : 'Client-side render');

  const regToken = searchParams.regToken;
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const authToken = cookieStore.get('auth_token')?.value;
  let regId = null;

  const reqOptions = {
    ...(regToken && { method: 'POST' }), // Corrected from emailRegToken to regToken
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` },
  };

  console.log({ regToken });

  if (regToken) {
    const apiUrl = `${process.env.MY_API_URL}/api/finalizeRegistration?registrationToken=${encodeURIComponent(regToken)}`; // Corrected to use regToken
    const finalizeRegRes = await fetch(apiUrl, reqOptions);
    const finalizeRegData = await finalizeRegRes.json();
    regId = finalizeRegData[0]?.registrationId;
  } else {
    const registrationId = cookieStore.get('registration_Id')?.value;

    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(registrationId);
      regId = parsedData.registrationId;
    } catch (error) {
      regId = null;
    }
  }

  // Return success page if condition is met
  if (regId === -1 && !regToken) { // Updated emailRegToken to regToken
    console.log('Condition met: regId === -1 and !regToken');
    return (
      <SuccessPage
        title="Thank you! A confirmation email is on its way."
        buttonHref="/events"
        buttonCTA="Back to events"
        message="Please check your inbox and follow the instructions to complete your registration."
      />
    );
  }

  console.log('This should not be logged if regId === -1 and !regToken');

  // Additional API fetches
  const registrationResponse = await fetch(`${process.env.MY_API_URL}/api/Events/registration?registrationId=${regId}`, { // Updated to use MY_API_URL
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` },
  });
  const registrationData = await registrationResponse.json();

  const { eventId, name: PatronName } = registrationData[0];

  const eventResponse = await fetch(`${process.env.MY_API_URL}/api/Events/event?tokenId=${eventId}`, { // Updated to use MY_API_URL
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` },
  });
  const eventData = await eventResponse.json();

  return (
    <SuccessPage
      title="You've been successfully registered!"
      buttonHref="/events"
      buttonCTA="Back to events"
    >
      <Box mt={4}>
        <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
          <CardContent sx={{ padding: 0 }}>
            <Box mb={2}>
              <CustomCardImageContainer imageUrl={eventData[0]?.image[0]}>
                {!eventData[0]?.image[0] && <CardDefaultIcon icon={LibraryBooks} fontSize="cardSize" />}
              </CustomCardImageContainer>
            </Box>
            <Typography variant="h5">{eventData[0]?.name}</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
              {PatronName}
            </Typography>
            <EventTimeFrame sessions={eventData[0]?.event[0]?.sessions} />
            <EventSessions sessions={eventData[0]?.event[0]?.sessions} />
            <Typography variant="body2" mt={2}>
              {eventData[0]?.event[0]?.locationDetail}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
    </SuccessPage>
  );
}


What I Expect:
When the condition regId === -1 && !emailRegToken is met, I expect the function to stop further execution after the return, and the additional API calls should not be made.

What Actually Happens:
Even though the condition is met and the return happens, the log statement "This should not be logged if regId === -1 and !emailRegToken" still gets logged, indicating that the function keeps executing, and the API calls are still made.

Debugging Attempts:

I added logs before and after the return statement to confirm the condition was met and the return was reached.
I logged whether the code was running on the server-side or client-side using typeof window === 'undefined', and it confirmed the function was running server-side.
I suspect double execution might be happening due to SSR and client-side hydration, but I can’t pinpoint exactly what’s causing it.


Environment:

Next.js Version: 14
Router: App Router (no getServerSideProps available)
Rendering Mode: SSR with server-side components
Deployment: Vercel


Logs from my local:


Logs from Vercel:
Below are the logs that were recorded on Vercel, highlighting the problem:



responseStatusCode
requestUserAgent
level
message




-10
Vercel Edge Functions
error
TypeError: Cannot destructure 'eventId' as it is undefined.


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
error
TypeError: Cannot destructure 'eventId' as it is undefined.


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
info
This should not be logged if regId === -1 and !emailRegToken


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
info
null true


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
info
false true


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
error
Invalid JSON format: "undefined" is not valid JSON


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
info
{ registrationId: undefined }


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
info
{ emailRegToken: undefined }


-10
Vercel Edge Functions
info
Server-side render


500
Vercel Edge Functions
error
[GET] confirmation-message... status=500


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
Returning SuccessPage, code should stop here


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
regId: -1 emailRegToken: undefined


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
Condition met: regId === -1 and !emailRegToken


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
-1 true


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
true true


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ regId: -1 }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ parsedData: { registrationId: -1 } }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ registrationId: '{"registrationId":-1}' }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ emailRegToken: undefined }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
Server-side render


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
Returning SuccessPage, code should stop here


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
regId: -1 emailRegToken: undefined


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
Condition met: regId === -1 and !emailRegToken


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
-1 true


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
true true


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ regId: -1 }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ parsedData: { registrationId: -1 } }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ registrationId: '{"registrationId":-1}' }


-10
Chrome/128.0 Safari/537.36
info
{ emailRegToken: undefined }




My Question:
Why is the code after the return still being executed? How can I prevent this double execution or ensure that the code after the return doesn’t run once the condition is met?

can you wrap this console.log('This should not be logged if regId === -1 and !regToken'); in an if(regId ===-1 && !regToken) and check?

@TheTeabagCoder, thank for the help. I have wrapped the log in the a if statement as suggested and the result are slightly different.
The back-end does not log "This should not be logged if regId === -1 and !emailRegToken" but, the code after the return still gets executed.

According to the log I don't see such case where both console.log('Condition met: regId === -1 and !regToken'); and console.log('This should not be logged if regId === -1 and !regToken'); happened. Assume that the log started at Server-side render going upward
